# TeamCity doesn't pick up result of xUnit tests when testing .NET Core project

Tags: .net-core, teamcity, xunit, cakebuild

I have a small .NET Core project, where the complete build/test/deploy process is handled in a Cake script.

I have a powershell script that runs the cake script.

When running the script locally, I get the result of each failing xUnit test, but when running the same script through TeamCity's PowerShell runner, I don't get the result of each test, just a summary of the number of failing tests.

The Cake task:

```
Task("Test")
    .IsDependentOn("Clean")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        GetFiles("./tests/**/*.csproj")
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(file => DotNetCoreTest(file.FullPath));
    });
```

This Cake code runs "dotnet test" under the hood.

When running the script manually in PowerShell on the build server, I get this output:

```
Test run for c:\project\myproject\tests\Web.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Web.Tests.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.7.0
Starting test execution, please wait...
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.7397647]        Web.Tests.UnitTest1.Test1[FAIL]
Error Message:
 Assert.False() Failure
Expected: False
Actual:   True
Test Run Failed.
Total tests: 2. Passed: 1. Failed: 1. Skipped: 0.
Test Run Failed.
```

When running the same script with TeamCity's PowerShell runner, I get this instead:

```
[14:27:45]  [Step 1/1] Test run for D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\7ff27c4721bc4a68\tests\Web.Tests\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\Web.Tests.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0)
[14:27:45]  [Step 1/1] Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.7.0
[14:27:45]  [Step 1/1] Starting test execution, please wait...
[14:27:48]  [Step 1/1] Failed   Web.Tests.UnitTest1.Test1
[14:27:48]  [Step 1/1] Error Message:
[14:27:48]  [Step 1/1]  Assert.False() Failure
[14:27:48]  [Step 1/1] Expected: False
[14:27:48]  [Step 1/1] Actual:   True
[14:27:48]  [Step 1/1] Test Run Failed.
[14:27:48]  [Step 1/1] Total tests: 2. Passed: 1. Failed: 1. Skipped: 0.
```

As you can see, it's missing the one line containing the name of the failing test.

Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I'm getting a similar (ish) issue.

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. I have upgraded TeamCity and upgraded the project to .NET Core 2.1, but I still have the same issue. Maybe it's just something silly, like TeamCity hiding all lines that start with "["

Comment: @mcintyre321 if you still struggling with it my answer may help. I have just solved it for my project by installing the package.

Comment: I just got the test to pass silently in the end :/ thanks, though!

Comment: I initially thought I had this same issue, but in the end I had forgotten to add the `XML report processing` build feature, thought adding this might help someone out...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Test .NET Core projects with TeamCity](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2017/04/test-net-core-with-teamcity/) article explains this behavior.

You have to install the [TeamCity.VSTest.TestAdapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TeamCity.VSTest.TestAdapter/) package to grab the output from the tests.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the same problem, but I ran into a similar issue when I recently upgraded from dotnet v2.0.8 to v2.1.0. In my case, after upgrading I no longer got *any* output from unit tests in Teamcity.

So far, the only workaround I have found was to use the dotnet xunit CLI tool in my unit test build step in Team City.

Note: This command can only be run from within the project using the command "dotnet xunit -teamcity".

It should be possible to configure this to run with Cake using the DotNetCoreTool alias.

Answer (score 0):

Tests might not be reported correctly for .NET Core xunit test projects when logging verbosity levels is minimal or quiet because of [issue 1706](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1706), so try avoiding using these verbosity levels.